# Adding onBlur and onFocus events

Tags: kentico

My company is currently looking into making our website "Web Accessible". I'm very rough when it comes to using Kentico (v8.2.50), but that's the CMS that is driving our site.

Running the front page through a Web Accessibility Checker, we encountered this warning on our main menu strip:

```
script not keyboard accessible - onmouseout missing onblur

onmouseover event handler missing onfocus event handler.
```

The fix sounds simple, but I'm not sure where to add these events. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Did you manage to get a working solution, or do you still need assistance?

Comment: Not yet.. still working on some other possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how your site has been put together.  If the site has been built using the portal engine, you're probably able to find the markup that you're looking for in one of the transformations.  There is a possibility that you're using the `CMSListMenu` control which for restricted flexibility in terms of markup.  Without a little more information or a page to look at it is hard to tell.

As for looking through transformations, I can highly recommend [Search for Kentico](http://www.bizstreamtoolkit.com/products/search) to help find things within the CMS, it's been invaluable on a number of occasions when looking for specific markup.  What it can do is help you locate things within Kentico by very quickly looking through the templates and transformations etc.

Comment: If you are using CSSListMenu and your menu is quite simple, you may want to consider using a Basic Repeater instead to give yourself more control.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a look. Appreciate the help.